# При открытии страницы медленно появляется содержимое

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Как на `jQuery` сделать, чтобы при открытии страницы медленно появлялся контент? Я имею в виду:

```
fadeIn();
```

Comment: Уважаемый, если вам помог ответ, не забудте принять его!

Comment: Принял щас:) Ибо забыл :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').fadeIn(100);
});
```

Примерно так, думаю принцип понятен.

Comment: Маленькая поправочка, на всяк случай - перед этим в выводе html или даже в css написать body{display:none}

Comment: Вот теперь это имеет смысл) Спасибо)

Comment: Да пожалуйста! Не забывайте принимать ответ ;)